# Layar - Opening a url in Layar using the native browser

Tags: uri, layar

Unfortunately the only answer to this I've found references out of date references to the old deprecated Layar documentation so here goes...

I've got a Layar AR set up with a simple link out to some Branch.com conversation areas. Problem is, the link opens up in Layar's webview browser. On Android, it works fine, however on iOS, Branch will ask that the user use Safari to post comments and such.

Question being, is there a way to get the links in Layar to open up the native browser of the OS instead of in the webview browser? From what I can see, there's no URI to facilitate this as the http uses the webview browser.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up speaking with the people from Layar, and presently it's not possible to force a link into the native browser. It's an issue that's been logged to the dev team and should show up in future releases.

In the meantime, we've decided to use individual twitter tweet pages to facilitate the "conversations".